# Generic method reading objects from large XML files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, generics, interface

The scenario here is with XML, but I think it might be rather generic related.

I'm trying to deserialize certain types of object from XML files. The procedures are the same for these types, therefore I'm using generic methods. XML files are large, so I'm combining `XmlReader` and `XmlSerializer`.

Example of getting the all the objects of a certain type:

```
public static List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IMyXml, new()
{
    var toReturn = new List<T>();
    T t = new T();
    string fileName;
    // different types are located in different XML files
    if (t.Type == XmlTypeEnum.A) fileName = "A.xml";
    else if (t.Type == XmlTypeEnum.B) fileName = "B.xml";
    else throw ... ;

    using (var stream = GetStreamFromResource(fileName)) //get file from embedded resource
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing(t.ParentName);
            while (reader.ReadToFollowing(t.SelfName))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                t = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadSubtree());
                toReturn.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

While all the types implement a common interface

```
[XmlType]
public interface IMyXml
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    string ParentName { get; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    string SelfName { get; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    XmlTypeEnum Type { get; }
}
```

The issues here:

- Generic types are not supposed to be `if`-ed (am I right though?), I have to add an enum as property in order to achieve that
- Interface cannot have static properties, I have to instantiate a dummy object to retrieve properties

So the code here looks kinda weird to me, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There´s no purpose in having a **generic** method that switches on the **actual** types at runtime. In fact a generic member should not make **any** assumptions on the actual types. The fact that you crate an instance of `T` just to determine the type seems also odd to me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere : I agree, I think that's a better description of those two issues. So what would be, if I may ask, the best practice to read these different objects from xml ?